# Busca por nomes similares ou com erro de digitação - MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

Estou buscando realizar um pesquisa em uma tabela contendo o nome dos produtos. Criei um FULLTEXT para otimizar a performance das consulta.

```
SELECT  * FROM tabela WHERE MATCH (campo) AGAINST ('Picant*Defumad*' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Resultado:

```
1 LOMBO DEFUMADO PICANTE FATIADO PRIETO BANDEJA

2 CAFÉ PICANTE

3 BISC TAP SNACK CURCUMA E PAPPRICA DEFUMADA 25G
```

Nessa buscar já obtive uma melhoria de não ser considerada a ordem que as palavras foram digitas, como no 1º resultado apresentado. Mas também preciso que caso o usuário digite `"PICATE"`, ele busque os registro que são semelhantes como no caso de `PICANTE` .

Já tentei utilizar outras formas de MODO como no caso do `IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE`, mas não solucionou o problema.

Comment: *"Mas também preciso que o caso ou o usuário digite "PICANTE""* não entendi bem a dúvida, seria como bucar "PICANT*", mas  nesse caso "PICANTE*"

Comment: No caso, preciso fazer uma busca por palavras similares, 

Exemplo: **"PICATE"**, onde falta o **N**, ele busque todos os registro que tenho **"PICANTE"**.

Comment: existe um recurso chamado `SOUNDEX`, procure a respeito

Comment: A função SOUNDEX não se encaixa na minha forma de busca, pois o mesmo utiliza um algoritmo fonético, e nesse caso tenho um erro de digitação que pode comprometer a fonética do texto.

Já realizei teste com o SOUNDEX.

Comment: nesse caso não há nada pronto pra te ajudar, vai precisar criar dicionários de palavras semelhantes e passar para  a query

Comment: O problema que a tabela chega a conter mais 1 milhão de registro. Na aplicação utilizo PHP, e consegui fazer uma busca que já me retorna o que preciso, porém aloco todos os valores do BD em memória para que possa tratar e isso consome muito recurso de máquina.

Comment: Estou vendo um forma de replicar o código PHP para uma função MySql.

Comment: No Oracle já fiz por Jaro-Winkler e edit_distance combinadas , achei para Mysql https://gist.github.com/TheHiddenHaku/7229861    doc Oracle https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/u_match.htm#ARPLS352

Comment: pq não usar REGEX?

Answer (score 0):

Uma opção é usar REGEXP. Segue exemplo replicável:

```sql
CREATE DATABASE supermarket;
use supermarket;
CREATE TABLE products (id INT, name VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO products (id,name)
VALUES (1,"LOMBO DEFUMADO PICANTE FATIADO PRIETO BANDEJA");
INSERT INTO products (id,name)
VALUES (2,"CAFÉ MOGIANA 250g");
INSERT INTO products (id,name)
VALUES (3,"CAFÉ PICANTE");
INSERT INTO products (id,name)
VALUES (4,"CATCH-UP PICATE");

SELECT *
FROM supermarket.products
WHERE name REGEXP 'PICA(N|)TE'
```

Retorna:

```
+------+-----------------------------------------------+
| id   | name                                          |
+------+-----------------------------------------------+
|    1 | LOMBO DEFUMADO PICANTE FATIADO PRIETO BANDEJA |
|    3 | CAFÉ PICANTE                                  |
|    4 | CATCH-UP PICATE                               |
+------+-----------------------------------------------+
```

Neste exemplo usei uma regex muito simples, usando as informações que você deu. Mas essa expressão regular pode ficar mais complexa para abranger os casos que você deseja.

Comment: Se o usuário escorregar o dedo e escrever `PICAMTE` vai ter que criar outra regra só para cobrir esse erro e assim deverá ser feito uma regra para cada erro de digitação possível o que torna essa abordagem inviável.

Comment: nessa caso não bastaria fazer `PICA(M|N|)TE`?

Comment: ë uma pesquisa se digitar "LONBO" vai ter que criar a regra do lombo, mas também pode ele pode digitar "LONBOO", "LAMBO", "LAMVO", para cada uma das infinitas palavras que o usuário pode digitar terá que criar infinitas regras de de tratamento de erros.